# How to animate ListBox Items on MouseEnter and MouseLeave events using C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, listboxitem

I can't capture/trigger OnMouseEnter or OnMouseLeave events through C# code for list items. To be clear, I don't need an OnSelectedItem event.

What I want to do is to be able to handle the OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave events for ListBoxItem which will start the DoubleAnimation for that ListBoxItem - I want to enlarge its font on MouseEnter and restore to original size on MouseLeave.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this (as part of the ListBox's DataTemplate):

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger
        SourceName="BorderControl"
        RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderControl"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    To="DarkRed" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger
        SourceName="BorderControl"
        RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderControl"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    To="WhiteSmoke" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

via http://www.dotnet-blog.com/index.php/2009/01/29/how-to-style-and-animate-a-wpf-listbox/