# How to Reverse WPF Storyboard animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, expression-blend

I've created a WPF Storyboard animation on an image in Expression Blend 4. On hover, the image gradually blurs. Is there any way I can have the Storyboard be undone or reversed when the mouse leaves the image? I could make it trigger Storyboard.Remove() but that wouldn't actually play through the Storyboard backwards.

Is there any way I can accomplish that within Expression Blend 4?

Comment: I don't use Expression Blend, but maybe you want to work on the xaml directly? To reverse a storyboard by another event, the most easiest way is to create a new storyboard doing the animation in reverse order and tag it to that event

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I was trying to avoid creating yet another storyboard. Thanks for the input.

Comment: So far if "do-and-reverse" is triggered by a single event, it can be easily done,but for ur case, it is 2 separate event. Will be interested to know of a convenient way through xaml alone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using Blend, you should take advantage of Blend's support for the `VisualStateManager`.  All you have to do is describe what the object looks like in its various states, like `MouseOver` and `Normal` and how long the transitions between various states are, and the visual state manager works out how to transition between states.

An image doesn't have any visual states but you can edit a `Button` template and make its content an image and then edit the states for the button.  I've done this and cleaned up the XAML to demonstrate the technique:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Image x:Name="image" Height="100" Width="Auto" Source="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" Margin="0,0,-25,0">
                            <Image.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
                            </Image.Effect>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="15"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that Blend does all this for you but understanding the XAML will help.  Here's a Blend-oriented tutorial:

- [MORE ARTICLES ON VISUAL STATE MANAGER](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2008/07/11/more-articles-on-visual-state-manager.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Making into a Button is sort of a bummer, but as long as it functions correctly, I can deal with it. Thanks!

Comment: You can see in my example how you can "style away" all the button-ness: no chrome, no border, no superfluous mouse-over behavior, etc.  But if you read the links I sent, it will show you how to create your own state groups and states like MouseOver and Normal for any type of element.  So, no, it doesn't have be or look like a button.

Comment: This is not the answer to "How to Reverse WPF Storyboard animation?". -.-'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is on this Answer:

[How to animate ListBox Items on MouseEnter and MouseLeave events using C#/WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942149/how-to-animate-listbox-items-on-mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-using-c-wpf)

Comment: under his question, he did commented that he wanted to avoid creating another storyboard