# Animation run forward and then reverse back to original state

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, animation, .net-4.0

Is there any simple way to run a WPF storyboard based animation normally and then to run it in reverse to return all things to their original state?

Preferably, I would like to do this programatically:

```
Storyboard sb=new Storyboard();

...

sb.Begin();

// Now how to do I run sb in reverse, to move things to where they were 
// before the sb started?
```

For example, you might have an animation where an ellipse moves from left to right and you would like for it at the end to move back to the left, where it began:

[image]

Comment: In one triggered run would be preferable, but if there is an easier way to do it in two I would like to see that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting [`AutoReverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.autoreverse.aspx) to `true` then?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, but it would be nice to see how to run an animation in reverse manually, as well (after it completes).

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: I tried to that too once and did not find an easy method, so i ended up duplicating the SB and changed all the `To` values to their origin. Maybe i overlooked something though...

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: Oh yeah, the visual state manager might be an option ([related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665529/how-to-reverse-wpf-storyboard-animation)).

Answer (score 0):

```
Storyboard sb=new Storyboard();
sb.AutoReverse=true;
...

sb.Begin();

 // Now how to do I run sb in reverse, to move things to where they were 
// before the sb started?
```