# WPF Styled button not resetting to default after it is clicked

Tags: wpf, button

I styled a button half using expression blend and half by hand, and it works pretty good except that once a button is clicked, it remains in the "pressed" state until i click another button. MouseOver works fine though. Any idea on how to fix it?

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonShrinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="glassCube">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="glassCube">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="outerRectangle">
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="outerRectangle">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="outerRectangle">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="innerRectangle">
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0"/>
                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="innerRectangle">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="innerRectangle">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="outerRectangle" Fill="Transparent" RadiusY="20" RadiusX="20" Stroke="GhostWhite" StrokeThickness="5">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="innerRectangle" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="12" RadiusY="20" RadiusX="20" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="5">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="glassCube" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="5" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.2"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.4"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.6"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.8"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsCancel" Value="False"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="glassCube" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="outerRectangle" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="glassCube" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="glassCube" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="outerRectangle" Value="GhostWhite"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="glassCube" Value="GhostWhite"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="glassCube" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="outerRectangle" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="glassCube" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="myContentPresenter">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <BlurEffect  Radius="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="glassCube" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="outerRectangle" Value="GhostWhite"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="glassCube" Value="GhostWhite"/>
                        <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="myContentPresenter">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <BlurEffect  Radius="0"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="glassCube" Value="0.7"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="glassCube" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation from your MouseEnter event isn't reversed when your mouse leaves the button.

Create an animation that will reverse the actions of the MouseEnter animation and apply it to the MouseOut event.

Related answer / example : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942149/how-to-animate-listbox-items-on-mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-using-c-wpf)

Comment: When IsPressed is set to false, the values of the first trigger will be unapplied automatically. You don't need to manually "reset" them.

Comment: That solves a bit of the issue, but the button is still shrank, and the outerRectangle is still of the color of HighlightBrushKey. Basically, I guess my question is: How to "undo" the storyboard when the Trigger is false?

Comment: I edited the code, most errors are gone doing what you suggested to other triggers as well. I also added a multitrigger for IsPressed + IsMouseOver so that it doesn't overlap with the simple IsMouseOver.

Comment: @FatalBaboon : i changed my answer, this is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: It's kind of sad that StoryBoards are not automatically "reversed", I can imagine scenarii where it would be a pain to do the job twice =X

Comment: There has been a lot of debate over this and how it could be done.
You can autoreverse a storyboard, but to make the forth-when-mouse-over and back-when-mouse-out animation work requires access to the storyboard from code-behind, which is difficult if the storyboard is (in) a resource.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the isfocused. If you click on the Button it will get the focus. so your focused trigger will work. If you move the focus or tab to some other control it will be ok.

```
 <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    TargetName="glassCube"
                                    Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                    TargetName="outerRectangle"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                    TargetName="glassCube"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
```